# Mounting Network Files

Tags: mount

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and a NAS (QNAP TS-219P+) (IP adress: 192.168.0.111) on which SAMBA is running.

I wanted to mount some files of the NAS using mounting points in `/media`. So I created for each NAS file a corresponding file in `/media` for example connecting NAS/transfer to `/media` transfer using `chown` and `chmod`. In `fstab` I added the necessary line, for example:

```
//192.168.0.111/transfer /media/transfer cifs user=juergen,passwd=1234 0 0
```

and so on

In Nautilus the NAS file is initially shown as mounted in 'Geräte' (german). In English I think it would be 'Devices'. After a short while the mounted file appears in 'Rechner' (in German language). In English I think it should be 'Computer'.

I can access the NAS files. But I am not able to change the owner and the user of for example `/media/transfer` from root root to juergen juergen. Using the command `sudo chown -c juergen /media/transfer` in the terminal line it is said that root root has changed to juergen juergen but using the command `ls -l` again root is shown as the owner.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu only for some months.

Comment: user200179 - if you are the person who has added two answers which have now been deleted, please use the contact us link at the bottom of this page to ask for all of your accounts to be merged. Once done, you'll be able to edit your question with further details. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change ownership of a mountpoint; I don't know if that's possible, but neither I see the use of that.

I guess what you want to achieve is to be able to access R/W the files on the remote drive as juergen, not only as root. In that case, add the `uid` option to your fstab line:

```
//192.168.0.111/transfer /media/transfer cifs user=juergen,passwd=1234,uid=juergen 0 0
```